# Mysql query delete is not deleting the data from my database eventhough I'm getting success message and API status code 200 ok

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-delete, sql-limit

This delete query is not deleting the Dress from the table

```
pool.sql('delete from  `Dress` where `did`=\'' + did +'\'', function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    callback({ 'ack': '0', 'error': 'internal error' });
                } else {
                    var res = pool.data(result)
                    callback({ ack: '1', 'msg': 'dress-deleted', res:res });
                }
            }
```

I was trying to use limit with delete to delete data of count 6000 in pieces, thought to start with count 10-20 in order not to crash the database, limit was not working so started trying just delete turns out limit is working delete is not. Select query with and without limit is working.